# javascript form.submit() losing querystring created by GA _linkByPost

Tags: javascript, forms, post, query-string

We have a booking form that POSTs to the parent company website. Because this is a different domain we need to implement the GA _linkByPost to pass the GA tracking cookie info across domains.

As the booking form is in a .NET user control it does a postback. On postback we validate, wrap up the booking info, and write a form back to the client with hidden elements required by the target booking engine and add line of javascript to submit the form.

Below is the javascript function I'm using to submit the form:

```
function postBookingForm() {
  var thisForm = document.getElementById('PostForm');
  _gaq.push(['_linkByPost', thisForm]);
  thisForm.submit();
}
```

And the relevant form info:

```
<form id="PostForm" name="PostForm" action="ClientBookingEngineUrl" method="post" >
    booking form info in here
</form>
```

The result is that we fill in the form, hit submit which does a round trip to the server generates a new form and POSTs the info. This all works fine apart from the URL loses the GA cookie info from the query string. If I comment out the form submit line and look at source code I can see the GA cookie info on the querystring - but when posting, I do not see the querystring (using Fiddler).

To clarify:
 The above technique works and does what we want with regards to POSTing form data to the booking engine and taking the user there.
 If the submit line is commented out you can see the form with the modified action that has the GA stuff appended (using Firebug).
 If the form is submitted with the submit line, the querystring info is removed (confirmed by Fiddler).

Am I missing something obvious? Are there some gotchas regarding JS submit, form POSTs and querystrings? Or is there a simple trick I'm missing?

Cheers

**EDIT 1**

An oddity has occured.

If I alert the form action before and after the _gaqPush then we can see the URL in its before and after state and it's as expected.

```
alert('1 form action = ' + thisForm.action);
_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', thisForm]);
alert('2 form action = ' + thisForm.action);
```

Alert 1 shows the pre-modified action and alert 2 shows the action with the GA info.
With the alerts in place it submits WITH the GA info in the query string.
If I comment out the alerts the GA info is NOT in the query string...

I'm starting to think the form or something is not ready so I'm trying it with JQuery's document ready.

**EDIT 2**

Wrapping the method call in document ready doesn't help. I'm confused as to why action URL is correct AFTER displaying it in an alert but incorrect if I don't alert it.

Comment: Thanks for typo corrections. I know the difference between loose and lose honest. I blame it on stress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this for posterity.

The problem is the _qaq (Google Analytics Queue) hasn't had time to modify the form before the call to submit() the form.

The solution is to push a function onto the _gaq object that submits the form so it will happen directly after the form modification is done.

```
function postBookingForm() {
    var thisForm = document.getElementById('PostForm');
    _gaq.push(['_linkByPost', thisForm]);
    _gaq.push(function() { thisForm.submit(); });
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I can use this instead of a delay?

Comment: That is correct - this will run correctly without resorting to delays or timeout functions since all things pushed to the queue run sequentially in the order they were pushed, one at a time. So the submit happens after modifying the form.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple HTML page that calls _gaqPush and submits immediately. This also fails.
Adding a 1000ms delay works (for the most part) so I suspect the alerts just gave the GA script time to modify the form.

I'm closing/accepting this as it seems down to submitting the form too quickly after the GA call.